# Using TextView resources in non activity class. MainActivity stops with "Exception despatching input event."

Tags: google-maps, android-layout, android-mapview, android

I am trying to `setText()` to a `TextView` resource from a layout XML file.

when user clicks on a marker in Google map. This is the code that I've written in `onTap()` for a marker.

Till I don't add `TextView`, my code works fine. It shows the dialog when I click the marker and everything works.

When I add these lines to `onTap()`, I run the application and click on marker and it stops saying `Unfortunately map has stopped`.

I am getting LogCat error message:

> Error dispatching input event

I have created a class CustomOverlayItem extending OverlayItem class. Tv_description `TextView` is part of layout file cutom_dialog.xml.

How can I call `setText()` to the `TextView` dynamically at the run time when user clicks marker?

```
@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, android.R.style.Theme_Dialog);
    TextView tv_description = new TextView(context);
    tv_description = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv2_description);
    tv_description.setText("checking");

    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
    dialog.show();

    return true;

}
```

Here is the logcat output :

```
07-31 11:59:16.271: E/Trace(2143): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-31 11:59:17.741: E/ZoomButtonsController(2143): Cannot make the zoom controller visible if the owner view is not attached to a window.
07-31 11:59:18.151: E/MapActivity(2143): Couldn't get connection factory client
07-31 11:59:28.531: E/InputEventReceiver(2143): Exception dispatching input event.
07-31 11:59:28.541: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2143): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
07-31 11:59:28.591: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2143): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-31 11:59:28.591: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2143):   at com.incubers.map.Markers.onTap(Markers.java:41)
07-31 11:59:28.591: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2143):   at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.onTap(ItemizedOverlay.java:453)
07-31 11:59:28.591: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2143):   at com.google.android.maps.OverlayBundle.onTap(OverlayBundle.java:83)
07-31 11:59:28.591: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2143):   at com.google.android.maps.MapView$1.onSingleTapUp(MapView.java:356)
07-31 11:59:28.591: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2143):   at com.google.android.maps.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:533)
07-31 11:59:28.591: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2143):   at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onTouchEvent(MapView.java:683)
07-31 11:59:28.591: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2143):   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7127)
07-31 11:59:28.591: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2143):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2170)
07-31 11:59:28.591: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2143):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1905)
07-31 11:59:28.591: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2143):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
07-31 11:59:28.591: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2143):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
07-31 11:59:28.591: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2143):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
07-31 11:59:28.591: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2143):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
07-31 11:59:28.591: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2143):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
07-31 11:59:28.591: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2143):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
07-31 11:59:28.591: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2143):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
07-31 11:59:28.591: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2143):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
07-31 11:59:28.591: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2143):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1925)
07-31 11:59:28.591: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2143):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1379)
07-31 11:59:28.591: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2143):   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2396)
07-31 11:59:28.591: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2143):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1873)
07-31 11:59:28.591: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2143):   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7307)
07-31 11:59:28.591: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2143):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3172)
07-31 11:59:28.591: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2143):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3117)
07-31 11:59:28.591: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2143):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4153)
07-31 11:59:28.591: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2143):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4132)
07-31 11:59:28.591: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2143):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4224)
07-31 11:59:28.591: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2143):   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
07-31 11:59:28.591: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2143):   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
07-31 11:59:28.591: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2143):   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
07-31 11:59:28.591: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2143):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
07-31 11:59:28.591: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2143):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-31 11:59:28.591: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2143):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-31 11:59:28.591: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2143):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-31 11:59:28.591: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2143):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-31 11:59:28.591: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2143):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-31 11:59:28.591: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2143):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-31 11:59:28.681: E/AndroidRuntime(2143): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-31 11:59:28.681: E/AndroidRuntime(2143): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-31 11:59:28.681: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at com.incubers.map.Markers.onTap(Markers.java:41)
07-31 11:59:28.681: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.onTap(ItemizedOverlay.java:453)
07-31 11:59:28.681: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at com.google.android.maps.OverlayBundle.onTap(OverlayBundle.java:83)
07-31 11:59:28.681: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView$1.onSingleTapUp(MapView.java:356)
07-31 11:59:28.681: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at com.google.android.maps.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:533)
07-31 11:59:28.681: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onTouchEvent(MapView.java:683)
07-31 11:59:28.681: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7127)
07-31 11:59:28.681: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2170)
07-31 11:59:28.681: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1905)
07-31 11:59:28.681: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
07-31 11:59:28.681: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
07-31 11:59:28.681: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
07-31 11:59:28.681: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
07-31 11:59:28.681: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
07-31 11:59:28.681: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
07-31 11:59:28.681: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
07-31 11:59:28.681: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
07-31 11:59:28.681: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1925)
07-31 11:59:28.681: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1379)
07-31 11:59:28.681: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2396)
07-31 11:59:28.681: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1873)
07-31 11:59:28.681: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7307)
07-31 11:59:28.681: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3172)
07-31 11:59:28.681: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3117)
07-31 11:59:28.681: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4153)
07-31 11:59:28.681: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4132)
07-31 11:59:28.681: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4224)
07-31 11:59:28.681: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
07-31 11:59:28.681: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
07-31 11:59:28.681: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
07-31 11:59:28.681: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
07-31 11:59:28.681: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-31 11:59:28.681: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-31 11:59:28.681: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-31 11:59:28.681: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-31 11:59:28.681: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-31 11:59:28.681: E/AndroidRuntime(2143):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: @nandeesh added logcat output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this line is wrong.

```
tv_description = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv2_description);
```

You are trying to find a `TextView` which is not present in your dialog.

Your dialog is a default `Dialog` which will not have this `TextView`. Do a `setContentView()` on your dialog with a layout, that has this `TextView`, before this above line.

Comment: So how can I do this? To add a TextView in a layout and add that layout to dialog?

Comment: R.layout.custom_dialog does this have tv2_description textview. If so just move the setContentview just after new Dialog

Comment: Yes. This layout file have tv2_description TextView. I tried moving setContentView after new Dialog. After I click on Marker, it gives the same logcat message.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to update your `TextView` via a `Handler` like this:

```
public Handler MainHandler = new Handler() 
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
    {
        _mytextview.setText((String)msg.obj);
    }
};
```

Send the message from your `onTap()` with :

```
Message _message = new Message();
_message.obj = "my text to update";
MainHandler.sendMessage(_message);
```

Hope it's help :-)

[EDIT] 
Here the code I tried :

custom_dialog.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/Overlay_Layout" android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:layout_margin="5dp" android:text="@string/empty" android:id="@+id/tv2_description">    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

In my `onTouchEvent()`:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(_context, android.R.style.Theme_Dialog);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
TextView tv_description = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv2_description);
tv_description.setText("checking");
dialog.show();
```

It's working for me..

Comment: Sometime I have problem with JavaNullPointerException on my components, have you tried to use Project->Clean (if under Eclipse) ? Your TextView is in the dialog ? Try to set the text after the setContentView.

Comment: Try to initialize the TextView (findViewById and setText) after setContentView and show. If it's did not work, I think you have a problem with your layout dialog, as suggested by nandeesh below.

Comment: Tried this too to initialize TextView after setContentView. Same logcat output. Is there any other way to achieve this? To setText to a TextView from a layout and add that layout to dialog.

Comment: It worked now. I restarted the application. Problem was exactly as chrisendymion said that I had to place setContentLayout before I use TextView.